# How do I vertically align a div so the backgrounds are perfectly matched and the text is in the center?

Tags: html, css, navigation, alignment, dropdown

The **HTML** is below and it is for a drop down box:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <h1>Dropdown Box</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS** is below, I have tried vertical align everywhere and can't seem to figure it out. The background of the nav button and the drop down are out of line.

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown h1 {
    background-color: #62dbfc;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    padding: 15px 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ededed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; 
}
```

Comment: You have not provided the CSS or a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to add `padding-left: 0` to the `.dropdown ul` styling. Here is a working example using your code:

```css
.dropdown { 
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown h1 {
    background-color: #62dbfc;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    padding: 15px 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.dropdown li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ededed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <h1>Dropdown Box</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using flexbox. Here's a great example:

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/